# I want text on my button tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, button, tags

Below mention is the code for my button

```
<button type="button"  Value="End Test" class="testBtns" style="float:right;"onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("StudentResult", "Student", new {  TestId = ViewBag.TestId ,style="color:white"} )'" />

i am not getting the "End Text" text on my button anybody know then please help
```

Comment: first of all correct this "onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("StudentResult", "Student", new {  TestId = ViewBag.TestId ,style="color:white"} )'"  with  "onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("StudentResult", "Student", new {  TestId = ViewBag.TestId },{ @style="color:white" } )'"

Comment: and just clarify your question...why you want text on button...you have button value not text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
<button type="button"  class="testBtns" style="float:right;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("StudentResult", "Student", new {  TestId = ViewBag.TestId ,style="color:white"} )'" >End Test</button>
```

The value attribute specifies the initial value for a `<button>` in a `<form>`, not the display text.

Answer (score 1):

Just correct your button as:

```
<button type="button"  class="testBtns" style="float:right;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("StudentResult", "Student", new {  TestId = ViewBag.TestId },new { @style="color:white" } )'">End Test</button>
```

text which you want to show in button should be enclosed between opening and closing tags of `button` `tag` and just correct `@url.action` you are mixing your 
`object route` and `html attributes`.